# Send button error message escaped

Tags: facebook

I'm integrating Send button in a site and faced with an issue that error message saying that to be able send to e-mail requires a public e-mail address is escaped. So that user can't click the link to setup @facebook address.

Here is error message screenshot

[image: http://imgur.com/XJ2Eb]

Is it possible to address it somehow or better report to developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302953569717849

Answer (score 1):

You need to claim your facebook email account. Click the following link after you've logged into your FB account.

http://www.facebook.com/messages/?setup